# StageWebView Scrolling - iOS AIR

Tags: iphone, flash, air, mobile-application, stagewebview

I am using the `StageWebView` Class to show html pages inside my *iOS* app. Everything is working fine except for the scrolling. It allowing the end-user to scroll the entire webview and is showing an unsightly gray background after reaching the end of the pages content.
My question is: ***Is there a way to disable the scrolling past the content of the page?***

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to do what. The `StageWebView` uses the iOS default browser which implements this feature (with a different background color, the behavior is the same though).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with this viewport?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

The important part is `user-scalable=no` which should remove the "scroll bounce" of the iOS browser.